# Objects: how to use the string declared before

Tags: java, object

I have the following code

```
    public void makeBaby() {
    String duplicate;
    boolean full = false;
    boolean same = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < park.length; i++) {
        if (park[i] == null) {
            full = false;
        } else if (i == park.length - 1 && park[i] != null) {
            full = true;
        }
        if (i != park.length - 1) {
            for (int j = 1; j < park.length; j++) {

                if (park[i].name.equals(park[j].name)) {
                    same = true;
                    duplicate = park[i].name;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!full) {
            System.out.println("The zoo is full. Cannot make any more babies");
        } else if (!same) {
            Animal duplicate = new Animal((float) 0.1 * park[i].mass,park[i].name, park[i].legs);
            addAnimal(duplicate);
        }
    }
}
```

As may be able to see in the code, I have to see if the array called park is full and if not, I need to make a baby animal. but before that, I also need to check if there are 2 animals that have the same type(name).

But I am experiencing problems with the line

```
Animal duplicate = new Animal((float) 0.1 * park[i].mass,park[i].name, park[i].legs);
        addAnimal(duplicate);
```

because the somehow java does not recognize the duplicate as the duplicate I set in the if statement above.

It is simply creating an animal called duplicate which is not what I want to do..

Comment: could you try : Animal duplicate = new Animal((float) (0.1 * park[i].mass),park[i].name, park[i].legs);

Comment: ``duplicate`` was declared as ``String`` before.

Comment: @qqilihq : does it compile as duplicate is declared twice?

Comment: i think i t compiles as second duplicate created in else-if  block is local to that block . correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Yup, give me the following error
'Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Duplicate local variable duplicate'

Comment: does addAnimal() take a String or an Animal?  if it takes a String, why are you creating the new Animal object Duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some other things that don't add up. For example:

full is declared as false. In the first if-statement:

```
    if (park[i] == null) {
        full = false;
```

which is already known.

If i am not mistaken:

```
    (!full)
```

is read as false and is meant to be executed when full = true.

```
    (full)
```

same goes for (!same)

I am no coding genius, so correct me if i'm wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables each named duplicate, I suspect that this is confusing you.

You have variable

```
 String duplicate;
```

and you have

```
 Animal duplicate
```

What is your intention? they are different types.

I suspect you mean:

```
 Animal theNewBaby ...
 addAnimal(theNewBaby);
```

And somewhere you intend the name of the new baby to be the String you stored in duplicate. As we can't see your Animal() constructor we don't know.

Comment: they are meant to be the same it's just that I want the two to refer to the same thing which is park[i].name

Comment: Two things of different types cannot be the same.

Comment: If you want to refer to the Animal by name, you'd probably be better off having String duplicate be of type animal and just getting the name from it later when you need it.  I'm making the assumption that park is an array of Animals, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems here... For one you have two duplicate variables... one String and one Animal. So depending on which parameter your addAnimal() method takes you might be grabbing the wrong duplicate.

Secondly, I don't believe your "Same" code check is going to work as you are looping through the same list twice. Unless you exclude the first found animal from your second j loop you are always going to find a match even when there is only one animal.

That might work for amoebas but not for elephants! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You only have to rename your variable `duplicate`(for example `sDuplicate` with the type as prefix), there is no other way if you want to give `addAnimal()` the string `duplicate` you set in the if statement. And add to the if condition:

```
&& i!=j
```

then your duplicate check will work.